# cloud firestore security rules change log

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cloud, firebase-security, audit-trail

I wanted to know if there is any way to monitor cloud firestore security rules changes. For example I want to know which user / service account changed the rules and at what time.

The Cloud Audit log service logs only admin related activities but nothing related to security rule changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

No audit trail is currently kept for changes to Firestore security rules. It's a valid feature request though, and might even be integrated into the exiting version history for rules. I recommend you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Thank you Frank. I have submitted for a feature request. Hopefully they consider it in the next release.